# Image preprocessing mean image subtraction

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a question regarding the preprocessing step "Image mean subtraction".
I use the [UCSD Dataset](http://www.svcl.ucsd.edu/projects/peoplecnt/) for my training.
One popular preprocessing step is the mean subtraction. Now I wonder if I am doing it right.
What I am doing is the following:

1. I have 200 gray scaled Train images
2. I put all images in a list and compute the mean with numpy:

   ```
   np.mean(ImageList, axis=0)
   ```

   This returns me a mean image
3. Now I subtract the mean image from all Train images

When I now visualize my preprocessed train images they are mostly black and have also negative values in them.
Is this correct? Or is my understanding of subtracting the mean image incorrect?

Here is one of my training images:

[image]

And this is the "mean image":
[image]

Comment: where is the mean image?

Comment: the second Image in my post. I also wrote above the Image "mean Image"

Comment: Oh silly me... failed to notice that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are doing it right.
As for the negative values: they are to be expected. Your original images had intensity values in range `[0..1]`, once you subtract the mean (that should be around ~0.5), you should have values in range (roughly) `[-.5..0.5]`.

Please note that you should save the "mean image" you got for test time as well: once you wish to predict using the trained net you need to subtract the **same** mean image from the test image.

**Update:**
In your case (static camera) the mean subtracted removes the "common" background. These settings seems to be in your favor as they focus the net to the temporal changes in the frame. this method will work well for you, as long as you test on the *same image set* (i.e., frames from the same static camera).

Comment: here would be the mean image: https://i.imgsafe.org/67eab4c82d.png
and here the image minus the mean image: https://i.imgsafe.org/67ee32c01f.png

Comment: @Biba in your case (static camera) the mean subtracted removes the "common" background. These settings seems to be in your favor as they focus the net to the temporal changes in the frame. this method will work well for you, as long as you test on the same image set (i.e., frames from the same static camera).

Comment: okay thank you Shai. I will try to train the net with the preprocessed images

Comment: @Shai Could you please add the part with the static camera to your answer? It is quite important that this is different to a setting like ImageNet, where you only compute the mean color.

Comment: @MartinThoma I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @MartinThoma what do you mean by mean Color? So is it not just like in the example above, just with three Color channels for RGB instead of one? Image ranges would be [ [-128...128] , [-128..128], [-128..128]] ?

Comment: @Biba: In ImageNet, you compute the mean color of all images, independent of the position. So you only have three values (R, G, B) for image net, but in your case (due to the static camera) it makes sense to have 1 * width * height values to compute.

Comment: ah okay good to know thank you for the explanation. So if my Training set has lots of similar Images like the above, but from other camera perspectives and Areas (so contain other Backgrounds), should i then also compute only the mean Color (gray value) and subtract it from all Training Images ??

Comment: @Biba if your test time frames comes from a different view, then you should consider a different "mean subtraction" strategy. I would suggest subtracting mean value per channel (i.e., a single value) instead of a mean value per-pixel (i.e., "mean image")

Comment: @Shai , Is it necessary to normalized the resulting image afterward? I mean we subtract the mage from its mean(take imagenet as an example), then some values become negative, are we better remove these negatives as well, or we should be fine? 
(I myself used to subtract the mean and go on, and didnt face any issues though! )

Comment: @Coderx7 it depends on how you initialize your weights and how you train your model. Most settings assume the inputs are i.i.d random variables with zero mean and init the weights accordingly. There's nothing wrong with "negative" pixel values in the input, as long as your net was trained with such inputs.

Comment: @Shai, Thanks alot, 
I usually use xavier initialization scheme, and do mean subtraction by specifying the mean file in caffe's datalayer. is there any other way of training that I do not know of? How do you usually train yours? 
I'm kind of confused to be honest! on one hand, image pixels seem to be correlated and not just random variables,  so I.I.D doesnt seem to be relevant in images?! am I right? on the other hand, I still dont know if images are better fed without any negative values or not (suppose I want to start from scratch, what should I follow to achieve the better result here)

Comment: @Shai, Did major netrowks, use negative images when training, or did they all normalize their inputs to have no negative images in their images?

Comment: @Coderx7 i.i.d assumption is indeed too much to ask and is used only when trying to provide some reasoning as to how to init weights for "training from scratch". I recommend reading [PReLU paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852) and the more recent [SELU paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02515) for a more "in depth" description on weights initialization.

Comment: @Coderx7 one usually prefers to "fine tune" nets rather than "train from scratch". Moreover, weights initialization usually assume "zero mean" inputs ("xavier" included) resulting with negative pixel values as inputs.